# Python: How to write this python one-liner in 'readable' way?

Tags: python

I have started to learn Python. I very confused with one-liner used in this code (5th line in the below code).

Can someone please explain to me how this one liner is working? May be re-write in verbose way?

```
multiset = [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
x = [0]
deltaSet = set(multiset)

for candidate in deltaSet:            
    if sum([(abs(candidate-member) in multiset) for member in x])  == len(x):
        for member in x:                            
            multiset.remove(abs(candidate-member))
        x.append(candidate)
        if len(x) == n: break
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like this code is using an advanced feature called list comprehension. It's understandable that a person new to Python wouldn't understand.

Comment: That's what I had thought, it must be using some advanced python feature. Can you please re-write in simple way?

Comment: The code's not deterministic, as the result depends on the order of iteration over deltaSet. That makes me think it's not correct, whatever it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the line you are looking at is:

```
sum([(abs(candidate-member) in multiset) for member in x])
```

First, there are far too many parenthesis there.  Lets get rid of the stuff we don't need:

```
sum(abs(candidate-member) in multiset for member in x)
```

Phew, that's a little better already.  Now lets actually look at the expression piece by piece:

```
abs(candidate - member) in multiset
```

This is self explanatory enough ... Is the absolute value of the candidate minus the member in the multiset?  If yes, the expression returns `True`, if not, the expression returns `False`.  Now what are the `member`?  Well, there's one for each thing in the iterable `x`.  So you're summing a bunch of `True` and `False`.  In python, booleans are subclassed from `int` (with `True == 1` and `False == 0`), the sum is basically counting the number of times that expression we talked about earlier is `True`.

Then they check if it is equal to the `len(x)` so basically, the code is checking if the expression is `True` for *every* member in `x`.  Fortunately, there's a better way to write this in python:

```
all(abs(candidate - member) in multiset for member in x)
```

If this is still confusing, we could rewrite this as a function (lets call it `f(x)`:

```
def f(x):
    """Equivalent to `all(abs(candidate - member) in multiset for member in x."""
    for member in x:
        if not abs(candidate - member) in multiset:
            return False
    return True
```

For some reference reading, in both cases, I've used generator expressions (which are similar to [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in syntax and meaning, but they generate the items "yielded" on the fly rather than materializing an entire list at once.  They're more memory efficient and faster for some operations.  They're particularly useful for cases where you don't need to look at every item to know the result (e.g. this one where a single `False` is enough to make the entire expression `False`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It really helped me understand the code. The sum/all is still confusing me. Can you write this is Java using multiple loops?

Comment: @Retr0spect -- I'm not sure that I can write it in Java because I don't know Java that well, and I don't remember how to do a forEach loop in Java (or if you even can ...).  I _can_ (and have) written the `all` expression as a very basic python function.  Hopefully that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks mgilson, I really appreciate your help. Edit: I have re-written the code in Java, but for some reason it does not produce the expected output. I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.